# Data updating in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorers 7,8 & 9

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm not sure if this is a knockout issue, a JSON issue or some other issue so I'll just explain it all.

I have a Web grid displaying a number of users. I can edit these members using a AJAX pop-up window. As part of this window I can assign roles to a particular user. As seen in the following image:

[image]

These roles are chosen from dropdown menus and if I want to apply multiple roles to a user I can add extra dropdowns. I do this using knockout's foreach binding.

Now after I hit save the webgrid columns update automatically in ALL browsers. However if I edit a user and give them extra roles, then hit save and then try and edit them again their newly added roles are not showing up in IE. Chrome and Firefox work perfectly however.

When I click on the 'save' button on this popup window the data is sent to the server  as JSON using the following code:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/Person/Save',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function(data) {
                        dlg.dialog("close");
                        $('#myUserGrid').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.debug(data);
                    }
                });
```

The relevant html and knockout code from the popup window view is as follows:

```
<tr>
        <td class="roleList" colspan="2">
            <table data-bind="foreach: RoleDdList">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        * Role:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.Roles, value: $data.role, optionsValue:'Id', optionsText:'Name'"> <!--,optionsCaption: 'No Role' -->
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.deleteRole, visible: $index()!=0">Delete Role</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <tr></tr>
```

There is a lot of code in the ViewModel but the relevant pieces are

```
 var Role = function(roleId, roleName) {
    this.Id = roleId;
    this.Name = roleName;
};

// Class to represent a row in the Roles DropDown List
function RoleDropDown(initialRole) {
    var self = this;
    self.role = ko.observable(initialRole);
    }

$(function () {

    function myViewModel() {
        var self = this;

//code relating to other fields

// Role Code
        self.Roles = new ko.observableArray();
        @{
            foreach (var pair in Model.RolesList)
            {
                @:self.Roles.push(new Role(@pair.Key,"@pair.Value"));
            }
        }


        // List of Role DropDowns
        self.RoleDdList = ko.observableArray([
                new RoleDropDown(self.Roles()[0])
            ]);


        // Add a Role (code for link on form)
        self.addRole = function() {
            self.RoleDdList.push(new RoleDropDown(self.Roles()[0]));
        };

        // Delete a Role
        self.deleteRole = function(num) {
            self.RoleDdList.remove(num);
        };

        //
        @{
            if(@Model.Roles!=null)
            {

                @:self.RoleDdList.pop();

                foreach (var selectedRole in Model.RoleNumbers)
                {
                    @:self.RoleDdList.push(new RoleDropDown(@selectedRole));
                }
            }
        }



    }

    vm = new myViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#formUser');


});
```

Any ideas for what the root of this problem is?

Comment: What data do you return from the ajax call?

Comment: the AJAX call posts the data from the popup form to the Controller action. 'data' represents the information returned from that action which is a html partialView